# How to pass the ConditionQuery in Mongosis SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb, ssis, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using Mongosis plugin in my SSIS package for loading data from MongoDB collection to SQLServer. I am able to successfully load data using the Mongosis DataFlow task, but currently the Condition query in MonoDB Source component>> Component properties>> ConditionQuery is hardcoded..

example: {"name":"xyz", branch:"abc"} inside the MongoDB Source>> Component properties tab.

I would like to avoid this hardcoding and pass the conditionQuery from outside the DataFlow task. Please suggest on how to go about this.